# ASP.net Redirect to the calling page

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, back

I have a page that calls another page with some query string parameters. I want to return back to that page after clicking on a button.

I have to mention that I write that code in a user control and I don't know what page called that second page.

Is there something like Back button in browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look at [Cross Page Posting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx).

Alternatively, if you are generating the link programatically you could include the returnUrl in the url e.g. `http://localhost/secondpage.aspx?returnurl=firstpage.aspx`

You can then read this querystring parameter in the secondpage and perform as redirect back once your work is done.

Answer (score 13):

Simplest way use javascript on client side with

```
window.back();
```

For server side you need to save the url referer in page_load:

```
if(!Page.IsPostback)
{
  ViewState["GoBackTo"] = Request.UrlReferrer;
}
```

and on a button click using Response.Redirect:

```
Response.Redirect( ViewState["GoBackTo"].ToString() );
```

---

***edit***: please note ppumkin's comment below!

Comment: the UrlReferrer is not work all the time, how ever this is a better way than the robert.

Comment: No it wont always work if they come direct to the page. Just catch it out like `if (ViewState["GoBackTo"] == null)` and if there is null just redirect to the default login page like `account.aspx` or similar. This is nice if you do not want to use forms authentications +1

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Request.UrlReferrer, but it is not necessarily sent from the client all the time:

```
        Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
```

Answer (score 1):

put this line of code on the page load event

```
 Btn_Back.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:history.back(); return false;");
```